# Securing Image URL and images

Tags: java, jsp, download, atg

We are working for an e-commerce site. When the end user clicks on **Wallpapers** tab, We are displaying the list of Wallpapers he purchased in a table.

Each row in a table has a download link. Clicking that link will opens a new page and downloads a **.jpg** file.

For download link we used anchor tag as follows:

`<a href ="/wallpapers/{skuid of the wallpaper}.jpg" download>Download</a>`

And while displaying each Wallpaper, there is a field where this SKU id is displayed. And all the sku ids are in sequence.

[SAMPLE SKU ID LIST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzUp2.jpg)

If a person purchases the any two wallpapers then he can easily figure out the other wallpapers and can easily download other wallpapers

Propose solutions that the end user cannot figure out the WALLPAPERS links.

Regards,

John

Comment: If the only "security" to prevent people from downloading all images is to only hand out the publicly available links after they payed you money you are in for a bad time anyways. I would propose to change the whole concept, to me it does not seem in any way useful.

Comment: What about using a hash function to produce a unique id starting from the sku id in the db?

Comment: Create webservice for fetching images.

Comment: Use a cloud based service for controlling access to downloads!  Lots of these available.   They are very cheap and give you the added benefit of a CDN.

Answer (score -2):

- Create Servlet or action, your download link should be point to that
  servlet/action.
- Add encrypyted SKU id in download link, which you will decrypt in
  servlet/action.
- After decrypting encrypted SKU id,Servlet/action should forward
  user request to particular image resource for actual download.

Comment: This is ATG so not very relevant.